# React hooks, update one state in response of another state update

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

How to have second state produced from first state and when the first one changes, make second state to react in response to update it ?

It worked but I am not sure how reliable is doing it that way, any suggestions ? Thanks.

```
    export default function App() {
      const [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
      const [length, setLength] = useState(arr.length);
      console.log(arr)
    
      const clickHandler = () => {
        setArr([...arr, arr.length+1])
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setLength(length + 1)
      }, [arr])
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h2>{length}</h2>
          <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: This example is very unrealistic since you can just check `arr.length`. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want it for other, realistic case, just that case was a bit complicated and long code and I was testing the issue by simplifying it down that way

Comment: the way you have it is fine I guess -- usually though state changes can happen "at the same time". instead of an using an effect to chain state updates aka just set both states inside the clickhandler

Answer (score 0):

so you want the *'second state'* (length) to be updated every time the length of the array changes. For that, you need an effect that will take the length of the array as a dependency (`arr.length`), and then set length to that value.

Also added a change to the `clickHandler` function as the state is computed from the previous state (check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) for further details)

This is how the final code would look

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(arr.length);
  console.log(arr);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setArr((arr) => [...arr, arr.length + 1]); // Change #1
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLength(arr.length); // Change #2
  }, [arr.length]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>{length}</h2>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```